# What do the terms "Landing Since New", FC, and FH mean on a Landing Gear RDAS?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-limitations

[image]

Could anyone able to tell me the "Landing Since New" Meant? and what is the FC and FH in here?

Thanks

Comment: Why would 29,253 Landing Flight Hours be "not relevant"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Landing Since New - *The definition is probably provided in Page 2 of the RAS*.

This basically means the number of hours spent Landing from the time the aircraft was brand new . Based on this figure the blades will have to be removed.

FH - Flight Hours - Basic unit for measuring length of time in service/before maintenance becomes due. The flight hour (FH) represents one hour of flight

FC - Flight Cycles - One Take Off and Landing

Comment: The number of hours spend landing?  How would you even determine this?  That is not what Landings Since New means.

Answer (score 3):

**Landing Since New**
This is the number of times that this nose gear has been used while installed on an aircraft when it landed.  I.e. the number of landings that it has been exposed to since the date that it was manufactured (new).

**FC**
The number of cycles (takeoffs/landings) that the aircraft from which the nose gear was removed from had at the time that it was removed.

**FH**
The number of hours of flight that the aircraft from which the nose gear was removed from had at the time that it was removed.

Note that the aircraft FC and FH don't really mean much in relation to the nose gear unless it has been installed on that aircraft since the time that they were both new.